# I2C client driver instantiation using Device Tree - probe did not get called

Tags: pi-3b+, device-tree

I am writing a sample and simple i2c driver in which I am trying to instantiate the
i2c client device using device tree overlay. I have got some **DTE** overlay sample which i have complied to **.dtbo** and placed it in **/boot/overlays** directory and also updated the **/boot/config.txt** followed by system reboot.

Now when I load the module the probe method does not get called. The **i2c_add_driver()** returns 0.  I am doing nothing but just printing a message in the probe function. I am not sure if the problem is with the **DTE overlay** i am using. Please help.

Since I am not manipulating the real device and just printing the messages  so in that case can i use any "**i2c compatible**" **DTE** entry which is already present in the system and see if that matches and probe function gets called ? This is to confirm if the problem is with the DTE overlay and not with my driver module ?

Thanks in advanced!

The DTE overlay i have used:

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {

```
fragment@0 {
    target = <&i2c_arm>;
    __overlay__ {
        status = "okay";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        sampledev {
            compatible = "i2c-eeprom";
        };
    };
};
```

};

And the attached image shows the driver code.  [image: driver code]

Comment: I suggest you also ask on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=107 where  I think you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into to the question. What operating system do you use?